# how update the value of useEffect() hook on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component and I have created a button inside it. I am also using a "Use_effect()" hook. My main is to re-render the functional component, update the use_effect() hook when the button is clicked.

```
const Emp_list = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getList(props.state.emp);
  }, []);

    return (

      <div>
        {props.state.emp.map((val ) =>   
               {val.feature_code}
               {val.group_code}
    <button onClick = {() => props.removeEmpFromList(val.feature_code)} > Remove </button>

        <EmpForm empList={props.state.emp} 
                    onChangeText = {props.onChangeText}
                   />
        </div>

        <button onClick=  {() => props.getdata (props.state)}>Get Names</button>
        <p> 
      </div>

    );

  };

export default Emp_list;
```

```
    removeEmpFromList = (i) => { 
      const remaining = this.state.emp( c => c.feature_code !== i)
      this.setState({
      emp: [...remaining]

        })

      }
```

When I click the Remove button , it will basically remove the employee from the list. The function `removeEmpFromList` will update the state.
The functional component `EmpForm` basically shows the list of all employees.

So I want to re-render the page so that, it updates the state value in useEffect() hook. So when EmpForm is called again on re-rending it shows the updated list.

Comment: What is `props.getList(props.state.emp)` intended to do?

Comment: So, basically this functional component is like another page. I'm using the hook to get the data on page load. So when the page loads I already see the list of employees.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the code for `removeEmpFromList()` ... but probably it updates the state by mutation therefor component gets the same object ref - compared shallowly - no difference, no reason to rerender.

Modify `removeEmpFromList()` method to create a new object for `emp` - f.e. using `.filter`.

If not above then passing entire `state` is the source of problem (the same reason as above).

Simply pass only `emp` as prop or use functions in `setState()` (to return a new object for the entire state) [this way](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: I have updated my question with the removeEmpFromList method. But even if I create a new object it wouldnt be called after my page load. it still has to re-render my funtional component

Comment: `.map` is ok ... Have you tried the second option? `<Emp_list emp={this.state.emp} /*getList, removeEmpFromList, getData, onChangeText etc*/ />` and of course `props.emp` instead of `props.state.emp`

Comment: I'm sorry but I dint understand the second option completely

Comment: pass `emp` as prop, not entire `state` - `<Emp_list emp={this.state.emp} ` instead of `<Emp_list state={this.state} `

Comment: No I need other items from state as well

Comment: `props.getdata (props.state)` doesn't make sense  ;) you don't need it here - `getdata` probably can work directly with state (this should be binded)

Comment: you can also pass both props: `<Emp_list emp={this.state.emp} state={this.state}`

Comment: sorry, didn't look carefully .... `const remaining = this.state.emp.filter( c => c.feature_code !== i)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Thanks for the help guys. 
So, it was not re-rendering because initally, useEffect() second parameter was [] , if you change it to props.state then it will update the changes made to the state and re-render the component automatically.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getList(props.state.emp);
  }, [props.state.emp]);
```